# Getting Youtube Channel ID using oAuth2.0 with Django/Python

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

Is there a way to obtain youtube channel ID or youtube userID using Google oAuth2.
I am able to retrieve 'profile' and email details using oauth.  Also provided scope for "youtube-readonly".
I want to achieve this using Python/Django

NB: General idea here is to show the Youtube Channel name and subscriber count of the logged in User. [user login through Google OAuth only.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got a way to implement with python.
Hope this will help anyone with similar question.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="id,status,snippet,statistics",
        mine=True
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```